# Python - Generate Random Operations for Postfix Notation List

Tags: python, nested-loops, postfix-notation

I'm attempting to produce a list that has four numbers (from 1 to 9) and three operations, represented using postfix notation. I'm trying to include the four main operations: +, -, *, and /.

There are 5 possible forms for this amount of numbers and operations, and they are as follows. An "O" represents a number and an "X" represents an operation:

```
OOXOOXX
OOOOXXX
OOOXOXX
OOXOXOX
OOOXXOX
```

I know that you have to use three nested loops. Given a list of four numbers called "s", I was trying something along the lines of this:

```
s = [1, 2, 3, 4]
ops = ['+', '-', '*', '/']

for i in ops:
    #Add a random operation from ops to one of the locations
    for i in ops:
        #Add a random operation from ops to one of the other locations
        for i in ops:
            s.append(i)
            #All of the instances have an operation in the last but I'm not sure how to 
            #select a random operation
```

Basically I'm stuck trying to select a random operation and place it in one of the designated locations. I'd also like to try and have every possible version of operations. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: Figured out how to get a list of all the possible operations. Still not sure how to place them in the list "s" though. I used the following:

```
allOps = list(itertools.product(ops, repeat=3))
```

Comment: Check out [Random.shuffle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.shuffle)

Comment: The `itertools.product` function is useful for things like this, since it gets rid of the nested loops. I'll try to write some code. And I think `itertools.permutations` will be useful here too.

Comment: If you want every possible version of operations then you might as well do that systematically rather than randomly choosing operations.

Comment: Why do each of your for loops use the variable `i`?

Comment: @PM2Ring Yeah, I realized the random operations wouldn't work well when I looked into itertools.

Comment: @EdwardMinnix Would having each loop using `i` cause an error? Would it be better to use a different variable per loop?

Comment: @Tom it won't necessarily cause an error, but it's generally an antipattern when nested loops use the same variable name. Ignoring the comments, your code is essentially the same as `for i in ops: s.extend([i] * len(ops) * len(ops))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a program that generates all the possible combinations of 3 out of 4 operators and slots them into your 5 possible RPN forms with the 4 numbers from `s` in order.

```
from itertools import product
import operator

all_ops = {
    '+': operator.__add__,
    '-': operator.__sub__,
    '*': operator.__mul__,
    '/': operator.__truediv__,
}

def rpn(cmd):
    ''' Evaluate a list of operations in Reverse Polish Notation '''
    stack = []
    for u in cmd:
        if u in all_ops:
            op = all_ops[u]
            y = stack.pop()
            x = stack.pop()
            stack.append(op(x, y))
        else:
            stack.append(u)
    # If command is well-formed there should be only 1 item left on the stack
    return stack[-1]

# Put all the different RPN expression patterns into a list of strings
# O: number, X: operator
forms = '''\
OOXOOXX
OOOOXXX
OOOXOXX
OOXOXOX
OOOXXOX
'''.splitlines()

s = [1, 2, 3, 4]

# Make all the combinations of length 3 of all the operators
for ops in product(all_ops.keys(), repeat=3):
    print(ops)
    for form in forms:
        # Make an iterator for this combination of operators
        opit = iter(ops)
        # Make an iterator for the numbers in s
        numit = iter(s)
        # Slot the operators and numbers into the pattern
        cmd = [next(opit) if c == 'X' else next(numit) for c in form]
        # Evaluate the command
        print(cmd, rpn(cmd))
```

**output**

```
('+', '+', '+')
[1, 2, '+', 3, 4, '+', '+'] 10
[1, 2, 3, 4, '+', '+', '+'] 10
[1, 2, 3, '+', 4, '+', '+'] 10
[1, 2, '+', 3, '+', 4, '+'] 10
[1, 2, 3, '+', '+', 4, '+'] 10
('+', '+', '-')
[1, 2, '+', 3, 4, '+', '-'] -4
[1, 2, 3, 4, '+', '+', '-'] -8
[1, 2, 3, '+', 4, '+', '-'] -8
[1, 2, '+', 3, '+', 4, '-'] 2
[1, 2, 3, '+', '+', 4, '-'] 2
('+', '+', '*')
[1, 2, '+', 3, 4, '+', '*'] 21
[1, 2, 3, 4, '+', '+', '*'] 9
[1, 2, 3, '+', 4, '+', '*'] 9
[1, 2, '+', 3, '+', 4, '*'] 24
[1, 2, 3, '+', '+', 4, '*'] 24
('+', '+', '/')
[1, 2, '+', 3, 4, '+', '/'] 0.42857142857142855
[1, 2, 3, 4, '+', '+', '/'] 0.1111111111111111
[1, 2, 3, '+', 4, '+', '/'] 0.1111111111111111
[1, 2, '+', 3, '+', 4, '/'] 1.5
[1, 2, 3, '+', '+', 4, '/'] 1.5
('+', '-', '+')
[1, 2, '+', 3, 4, '-', '+'] 2
[1, 2, 3, 4, '+', '-', '+'] -4
[1, 2, 3, '+', 4, '-', '+'] 2
[1, 2, '+', 3, '-', 4, '+'] 4
[1, 2, 3, '+', '-', 4, '+'] 0
('+', '-', '-')
[1, 2, '+', 3, 4, '-', '-'] 4
[1, 2, 3, 4, '+', '-', '-'] 6
[1, 2, 3, '+', 4, '-', '-'] 0
[1, 2, '+', 3, '-', 4, '-'] -4
[1, 2, 3, '+', '-', 4, '-'] -8
('+', '-', '*')
[1, 2, '+', 3, 4, '-', '*'] -3
[1, 2, 3, 4, '+', '-', '*'] -5
[1, 2, 3, '+', 4, '-', '*'] 1
[1, 2, '+', 3, '-', 4, '*'] 0
[1, 2, 3, '+', '-', 4, '*'] -16
('+', '-', '/')
[1, 2, '+', 3, 4, '-', '/'] -3.0
[1, 2, 3, 4, '+', '-', '/'] -0.2
[1, 2, 3, '+', 4, '-', '/'] 1.0
[1, 2, '+', 3, '-', 4, '/'] 0.0
[1, 2, 3, '+', '-', 4, '/'] -1.0
('+', '*', '+')
[1, 2, '+', 3, 4, '*', '+'] 15
[1, 2, 3, 4, '+', '*', '+'] 15
[1, 2, 3, '+', 4, '*', '+'] 21
[1, 2, '+', 3, '*', 4, '+'] 13
[1, 2, 3, '+', '*', 4, '+'] 9
('+', '*', '-')
[1, 2, '+', 3, 4, '*', '-'] -9
[1, 2, 3, 4, '+', '*', '-'] -13
[1, 2, 3, '+', 4, '*', '-'] -19
[1, 2, '+', 3, '*', 4, '-'] 5
[1, 2, 3, '+', '*', 4, '-'] 1
('+', '*', '*')
[1, 2, '+', 3, 4, '*', '*'] 36
[1, 2, 3, 4, '+', '*', '*'] 14
[1, 2, 3, '+', 4, '*', '*'] 20
[1, 2, '+', 3, '*', 4, '*'] 36
[1, 2, 3, '+', '*', 4, '*'] 20
('+', '*', '/')
[1, 2, '+', 3, 4, '*', '/'] 0.25
[1, 2, 3, 4, '+', '*', '/'] 0.07142857142857142
[1, 2, 3, '+', 4, '*', '/'] 0.05
[1, 2, '+', 3, '*', 4, '/'] 2.25
[1, 2, 3, '+', '*', 4, '/'] 1.25
('+', '/', '+')
[1, 2, '+', 3, 4, '/', '+'] 3.75
[1, 2, 3, 4, '+', '/', '+'] 1.2857142857142856
[1, 2, 3, '+', 4, '/', '+'] 2.25
[1, 2, '+', 3, '/', 4, '+'] 5.0
[1, 2, 3, '+', '/', 4, '+'] 4.2
('+', '/', '-')
[1, 2, '+', 3, 4, '/', '-'] 2.25
[1, 2, 3, 4, '+', '/', '-'] 0.7142857142857143
[1, 2, 3, '+', 4, '/', '-'] -0.25
[1, 2, '+', 3, '/', 4, '-'] -3.0
[1, 2, 3, '+', '/', 4, '-'] -3.8
('+', '/', '*')
[1, 2, '+', 3, 4, '/', '*'] 2.25
[1, 2, 3, 4, '+', '/', '*'] 0.2857142857142857
[1, 2, 3, '+', 4, '/', '*'] 1.25
[1, 2, '+', 3, '/', 4, '*'] 4.0
[1, 2, 3, '+', '/', 4, '*'] 0.8
('+', '/', '/')
[1, 2, '+', 3, 4, '/', '/'] 4.0
[1, 2, 3, 4, '+', '/', '/'] 3.5
[1, 2, 3, '+', 4, '/', '/'] 0.8
[1, 2, '+', 3, '/', 4, '/'] 0.25
[1, 2, 3, '+', '/', 4, '/'] 0.05
('-', '+', '+')
[1, 2, '-', 3, 4, '+', '+'] 6
[1, 2, 3, 4, '-', '+', '+'] 2
[1, 2, 3, '-', 4, '+', '+'] 4
[1, 2, '-', 3, '+', 4, '+'] 6
[1, 2, 3, '-', '+', 4, '+'] 4
('-', '+', '-')
[1, 2, '-', 3, 4, '+', '-'] -8
[1, 2, 3, 4, '-', '+', '-'] 0
[1, 2, 3, '-', 4, '+', '-'] -2
[1, 2, '-', 3, '+', 4, '-'] -2
[1, 2, 3, '-', '+', 4, '-'] -4
('-', '+', '*')
[1, 2, '-', 3, 4, '+', '*'] -7
[1, 2, 3, 4, '-', '+', '*'] 1
[1, 2, 3, '-', 4, '+', '*'] 3
[1, 2, '-', 3, '+', 4, '*'] 8
[1, 2, 3, '-', '+', 4, '*'] 0
('-', '+', '/')
[1, 2, '-', 3, 4, '+', '/'] -0.14285714285714285
[1, 2, 3, 4, '-', '+', '/'] 1.0
[1, 2, 3, '-', 4, '+', '/'] 0.3333333333333333
[1, 2, '-', 3, '+', 4, '/'] 0.5
[1, 2, 3, '-', '+', 4, '/'] 0.0
('-', '-', '+')
[1, 2, '-', 3, 4, '-', '+'] -2
[1, 2, 3, 4, '-', '-', '+'] 4
[1, 2, 3, '-', 4, '-', '+'] -4
[1, 2, '-', 3, '-', 4, '+'] 0
[1, 2, 3, '-', '-', 4, '+'] 6
('-', '-', '-')
[1, 2, '-', 3, 4, '-', '-'] 0
[1, 2, 3, 4, '-', '-', '-'] -2
[1, 2, 3, '-', 4, '-', '-'] 6
[1, 2, '-', 3, '-', 4, '-'] -8
[1, 2, 3, '-', '-', 4, '-'] -2
('-', '-', '*')
[1, 2, '-', 3, 4, '-', '*'] 1
[1, 2, 3, 4, '-', '-', '*'] 3
[1, 2, 3, '-', 4, '-', '*'] -5
[1, 2, '-', 3, '-', 4, '*'] -16
[1, 2, 3, '-', '-', 4, '*'] 8
('-', '-', '/')
[1, 2, '-', 3, 4, '-', '/'] 1.0
[1, 2, 3, 4, '-', '-', '/'] 0.3333333333333333
[1, 2, 3, '-', 4, '-', '/'] -0.2
[1, 2, '-', 3, '-', 4, '/'] -1.0
[1, 2, 3, '-', '-', 4, '/'] 0.5
('-', '*', '+')
[1, 2, '-', 3, 4, '*', '+'] 11
[1, 2, 3, 4, '-', '*', '+'] -1
[1, 2, 3, '-', 4, '*', '+'] -3
[1, 2, '-', 3, '*', 4, '+'] 1
[1, 2, 3, '-', '*', 4, '+'] 3
('-', '*', '-')
[1, 2, '-', 3, 4, '*', '-'] -13
[1, 2, 3, 4, '-', '*', '-'] 3
[1, 2, 3, '-', 4, '*', '-'] 5
[1, 2, '-', 3, '*', 4, '-'] -7
[1, 2, 3, '-', '*', 4, '-'] -5
('-', '*', '*')
[1, 2, '-', 3, 4, '*', '*'] -12
[1, 2, 3, 4, '-', '*', '*'] -2
[1, 2, 3, '-', 4, '*', '*'] -4
[1, 2, '-', 3, '*', 4, '*'] -12
[1, 2, 3, '-', '*', 4, '*'] -4
('-', '*', '/')
[1, 2, '-', 3, 4, '*', '/'] -0.08333333333333333
[1, 2, 3, 4, '-', '*', '/'] -0.5
[1, 2, 3, '-', 4, '*', '/'] -0.25
[1, 2, '-', 3, '*', 4, '/'] -0.75
[1, 2, 3, '-', '*', 4, '/'] -0.25
('-', '/', '+')
[1, 2, '-', 3, 4, '/', '+'] -0.25
[1, 2, 3, 4, '-', '/', '+'] -1.0
[1, 2, 3, '-', 4, '/', '+'] 0.75
[1, 2, '-', 3, '/', 4, '+'] 3.6666666666666665
[1, 2, 3, '-', '/', 4, '+'] 3.0
('-', '/', '-')
[1, 2, '-', 3, 4, '/', '-'] -1.75
[1, 2, 3, 4, '-', '/', '-'] 3.0
[1, 2, 3, '-', 4, '/', '-'] 1.25
[1, 2, '-', 3, '/', 4, '-'] -4.333333333333333
[1, 2, 3, '-', '/', 4, '-'] -5.0
('-', '/', '*')
[1, 2, '-', 3, 4, '/', '*'] -0.75
[1, 2, 3, 4, '-', '/', '*'] -2.0
[1, 2, 3, '-', 4, '/', '*'] -0.25
[1, 2, '-', 3, '/', 4, '*'] -1.3333333333333333
[1, 2, 3, '-', '/', 4, '*'] -4.0
('-', '/', '/')
[1, 2, '-', 3, 4, '/', '/'] -1.3333333333333333
[1, 2, 3, 4, '-', '/', '/'] -0.5
[1, 2, 3, '-', 4, '/', '/'] -4.0
[1, 2, '-', 3, '/', 4, '/'] -0.08333333333333333
[1, 2, 3, '-', '/', 4, '/'] -0.25
('*', '+', '+')
[1, 2, '*', 3, 4, '+', '+'] 9
[1, 2, 3, 4, '*', '+', '+'] 15
[1, 2, 3, '*', 4, '+', '+'] 11
[1, 2, '*', 3, '+', 4, '+'] 9
[1, 2, 3, '*', '+', 4, '+'] 11
('*', '+', '-')
[1, 2, '*', 3, 4, '+', '-'] -5
[1, 2, 3, 4, '*', '+', '-'] -13
[1, 2, 3, '*', 4, '+', '-'] -9
[1, 2, '*', 3, '+', 4, '-'] 1
[1, 2, 3, '*', '+', 4, '-'] 3
('*', '+', '*')
[1, 2, '*', 3, 4, '+', '*'] 14
[1, 2, 3, 4, '*', '+', '*'] 14
[1, 2, 3, '*', 4, '+', '*'] 10
[1, 2, '*', 3, '+', 4, '*'] 20
[1, 2, 3, '*', '+', 4, '*'] 28
('*', '+', '/')
[1, 2, '*', 3, 4, '+', '/'] 0.2857142857142857
[1, 2, 3, 4, '*', '+', '/'] 0.07142857142857142
[1, 2, 3, '*', 4, '+', '/'] 0.1
[1, 2, '*', 3, '+', 4, '/'] 1.25
[1, 2, 3, '*', '+', 4, '/'] 1.75
('*', '-', '+')
[1, 2, '*', 3, 4, '-', '+'] 1
[1, 2, 3, 4, '*', '-', '+'] -9
[1, 2, 3, '*', 4, '-', '+'] 3
[1, 2, '*', 3, '-', 4, '+'] 3
[1, 2, 3, '*', '-', 4, '+'] -1
('*', '-', '-')
[1, 2, '*', 3, 4, '-', '-'] 3
[1, 2, 3, 4, '*', '-', '-'] 11
[1, 2, 3, '*', 4, '-', '-'] -1
[1, 2, '*', 3, '-', 4, '-'] -5
[1, 2, 3, '*', '-', 4, '-'] -9
('*', '-', '*')
[1, 2, '*', 3, 4, '-', '*'] -2
[1, 2, 3, 4, '*', '-', '*'] -10
[1, 2, 3, '*', 4, '-', '*'] 2
[1, 2, '*', 3, '-', 4, '*'] -4
[1, 2, 3, '*', '-', 4, '*'] -20
('*', '-', '/')
[1, 2, '*', 3, 4, '-', '/'] -2.0
[1, 2, 3, 4, '*', '-', '/'] -0.1
[1, 2, 3, '*', 4, '-', '/'] 0.5
[1, 2, '*', 3, '-', 4, '/'] -0.25
[1, 2, 3, '*', '-', 4, '/'] -1.25
('*', '*', '+')
[1, 2, '*', 3, 4, '*', '+'] 14
[1, 2, 3, 4, '*', '*', '+'] 25
[1, 2, 3, '*', 4, '*', '+'] 25
[1, 2, '*', 3, '*', 4, '+'] 10
[1, 2, 3, '*', '*', 4, '+'] 10
('*', '*', '-')
[1, 2, '*', 3, 4, '*', '-'] -10
[1, 2, 3, 4, '*', '*', '-'] -23
[1, 2, 3, '*', 4, '*', '-'] -23
[1, 2, '*', 3, '*', 4, '-'] 2
[1, 2, 3, '*', '*', 4, '-'] 2
('*', '*', '*')
[1, 2, '*', 3, 4, '*', '*'] 24
[1, 2, 3, 4, '*', '*', '*'] 24
[1, 2, 3, '*', 4, '*', '*'] 24
[1, 2, '*', 3, '*', 4, '*'] 24
[1, 2, 3, '*', '*', 4, '*'] 24
('*', '*', '/')
[1, 2, '*', 3, 4, '*', '/'] 0.16666666666666666
[1, 2, 3, 4, '*', '*', '/'] 0.041666666666666664
[1, 2, 3, '*', 4, '*', '/'] 0.041666666666666664
[1, 2, '*', 3, '*', 4, '/'] 1.5
[1, 2, 3, '*', '*', 4, '/'] 1.5
('*', '/', '+')
[1, 2, '*', 3, 4, '/', '+'] 2.75
[1, 2, 3, 4, '*', '/', '+'] 1.1666666666666667
[1, 2, 3, '*', 4, '/', '+'] 2.5
[1, 2, '*', 3, '/', 4, '+'] 4.666666666666667
[1, 2, 3, '*', '/', 4, '+'] 4.166666666666667
('*', '/', '-')
[1, 2, '*', 3, 4, '/', '-'] 1.25
[1, 2, 3, 4, '*', '/', '-'] 0.8333333333333334
[1, 2, 3, '*', 4, '/', '-'] -0.5
[1, 2, '*', 3, '/', 4, '-'] -3.3333333333333335
[1, 2, 3, '*', '/', 4, '-'] -3.8333333333333335
('*', '/', '*')
[1, 2, '*', 3, 4, '/', '*'] 1.5
[1, 2, 3, 4, '*', '/', '*'] 0.16666666666666666
[1, 2, 3, '*', 4, '/', '*'] 1.5
[1, 2, '*', 3, '/', 4, '*'] 2.6666666666666665
[1, 2, 3, '*', '/', 4, '*'] 0.6666666666666666
('*', '/', '/')
[1, 2, '*', 3, 4, '/', '/'] 2.6666666666666665
[1, 2, 3, 4, '*', '/', '/'] 6.0
[1, 2, 3, '*', 4, '/', '/'] 0.6666666666666666
[1, 2, '*', 3, '/', 4, '/'] 0.16666666666666666
[1, 2, 3, '*', '/', 4, '/'] 0.041666666666666664
('/', '+', '+')
[1, 2, '/', 3, 4, '+', '+'] 7.5
[1, 2, 3, 4, '/', '+', '+'] 3.75
[1, 2, 3, '/', 4, '+', '+'] 5.666666666666667
[1, 2, '/', 3, '+', 4, '+'] 7.5
[1, 2, 3, '/', '+', 4, '+'] 5.666666666666666
('/', '+', '-')
[1, 2, '/', 3, 4, '+', '-'] -6.5
[1, 2, 3, 4, '/', '+', '-'] -1.75
[1, 2, 3, '/', 4, '+', '-'] -3.666666666666667
[1, 2, '/', 3, '+', 4, '-'] -0.5
[1, 2, 3, '/', '+', 4, '-'] -2.3333333333333335
('/', '+', '*')
[1, 2, '/', 3, 4, '+', '*'] 3.5
[1, 2, 3, 4, '/', '+', '*'] 2.75
[1, 2, 3, '/', 4, '+', '*'] 4.666666666666667
[1, 2, '/', 3, '+', 4, '*'] 14.0
[1, 2, 3, '/', '+', 4, '*'] 6.666666666666666
('/', '+', '/')
[1, 2, '/', 3, 4, '+', '/'] 0.07142857142857142
[1, 2, 3, 4, '/', '+', '/'] 0.36363636363636365
[1, 2, 3, '/', 4, '+', '/'] 0.21428571428571427
[1, 2, '/', 3, '+', 4, '/'] 0.875
[1, 2, 3, '/', '+', 4, '/'] 0.41666666666666663
('/', '-', '+')
[1, 2, '/', 3, 4, '-', '+'] -0.5
[1, 2, 3, 4, '/', '-', '+'] 2.25
[1, 2, 3, '/', 4, '-', '+'] -2.3333333333333335
[1, 2, '/', 3, '-', 4, '+'] 1.5
[1, 2, 3, '/', '-', 4, '+'] 4.333333333333333
('/', '-', '-')
[1, 2, '/', 3, 4, '-', '-'] 1.5
[1, 2, 3, 4, '/', '-', '-'] -0.25
[1, 2, 3, '/', 4, '-', '-'] 4.333333333333334
[1, 2, '/', 3, '-', 4, '-'] -6.5
[1, 2, 3, '/', '-', 4, '-'] -3.6666666666666665
('/', '-', '*')
[1, 2, '/', 3, 4, '-', '*'] -0.5
[1, 2, 3, 4, '/', '-', '*'] 1.25
[1, 2, 3, '/', 4, '-', '*'] -3.3333333333333335
[1, 2, '/', 3, '-', 4, '*'] -10.0
[1, 2, 3, '/', '-', 4, '*'] 1.3333333333333335
('/', '-', '/')
[1, 2, '/', 3, 4, '-', '/'] -0.5
[1, 2, 3, 4, '/', '-', '/'] 0.8
[1, 2, 3, '/', 4, '-', '/'] -0.3
[1, 2, '/', 3, '-', 4, '/'] -0.625
[1, 2, 3, '/', '-', 4, '/'] 0.08333333333333334
('/', '*', '+')
[1, 2, '/', 3, 4, '*', '+'] 12.5
[1, 2, 3, 4, '/', '*', '+'] 2.5
[1, 2, 3, '/', 4, '*', '+'] 3.6666666666666665
[1, 2, '/', 3, '*', 4, '+'] 5.5
[1, 2, 3, '/', '*', 4, '+'] 4.666666666666667
('/', '*', '-')
[1, 2, '/', 3, 4, '*', '-'] -11.5
[1, 2, 3, 4, '/', '*', '-'] -0.5
[1, 2, 3, '/', 4, '*', '-'] -1.6666666666666665
[1, 2, '/', 3, '*', 4, '-'] -2.5
[1, 2, 3, '/', '*', 4, '-'] -3.3333333333333335
('/', '*', '*')
[1, 2, '/', 3, 4, '*', '*'] 6.0
[1, 2, 3, 4, '/', '*', '*'] 1.5
[1, 2, 3, '/', 4, '*', '*'] 2.6666666666666665
[1, 2, '/', 3, '*', 4, '*'] 6.0
[1, 2, 3, '/', '*', 4, '*'] 2.6666666666666665
('/', '*', '/')
[1, 2, '/', 3, 4, '*', '/'] 0.041666666666666664
[1, 2, 3, 4, '/', '*', '/'] 0.6666666666666666
[1, 2, 3, '/', 4, '*', '/'] 0.375
[1, 2, '/', 3, '*', 4, '/'] 0.375
[1, 2, 3, '/', '*', 4, '/'] 0.16666666666666666
('/', '/', '+')
[1, 2, '/', 3, 4, '/', '+'] 1.25
[1, 2, 3, 4, '/', '/', '+'] 3.6666666666666665
[1, 2, 3, '/', 4, '/', '+'] 1.1666666666666667
[1, 2, '/', 3, '/', 4, '+'] 4.166666666666667
[1, 2, 3, '/', '/', 4, '+'] 5.5
('/', '/', '-')
[1, 2, '/', 3, 4, '/', '-'] -0.25
[1, 2, 3, 4, '/', '/', '-'] -1.6666666666666665
[1, 2, 3, '/', 4, '/', '-'] 0.8333333333333334
[1, 2, '/', 3, '/', 4, '-'] -3.8333333333333335
[1, 2, 3, '/', '/', 4, '-'] -2.5
('/', '/', '*')
[1, 2, '/', 3, 4, '/', '*'] 0.375
[1, 2, 3, 4, '/', '/', '*'] 2.6666666666666665
[1, 2, 3, '/', 4, '/', '*'] 0.16666666666666666
[1, 2, '/', 3, '/', 4, '*'] 0.6666666666666666
[1, 2, 3, '/', '/', 4, '*'] 6.0
('/', '/', '/')
[1, 2, '/', 3, 4, '/', '/'] 0.6666666666666666
[1, 2, 3, 4, '/', '/', '/'] 0.375
[1, 2, 3, '/', 4, '/', '/'] 6.0
[1, 2, '/', 3, '/', 4, '/'] 0.041666666666666664
[1, 2, 3, '/', '/', 4, '/'] 0.375
```

Beware, this code does no error checking, so it will crash if some combination attempts to divide by zero.